# Oldest Japanese Pronunciation for "When Is It?"

Tags: archaic-language

I'm writing a story with some... *very* old people, so I'm chasing down some very outdated pronunciations. What's the oldest known pronunciation for the sentence "When is it?"

(I'm not *directly* asking for an archaic pronunciation of「今、いつか？」because for all I know they'd've used different words entirely, but that's the sentence as it'd appear in modern Japanese.)

Comment: "When is it?" in what context? Do you mean "What time is it now"? But they don't have clock in oldest known times...

Comment: How old? Can you give a specific age or year they were born?

Comment: @broccoliforest - "When is it" in a very general "What century/year/Age is it" sense.

Comment: @Locksleyu - The character in question is Kushinada-hime, so "no, but she's older than the Kojiki". Sometime before 700 AD. I'll take what I can get, I know there's not much from that time period.

Comment: クシナダヒメ was a person(a god) in about the 1st century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell that this is absolutely correct as a word in Nara period, though.

In eight-hundreds, before 古今和歌集 was made, it seems that there was a conversation like this between Mikado and an editor.

http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~sg2h-ymst/yamatouta/sennin/arisue.html

```
貞観の御時、万葉集はいつばかり作れるぞと問はせたまひければ、よみてたてまつりける
(In the 貞観 era, Mikado asked me when 万葉集 had been made, and I replied in a poem.)
```

→when＝いつばかり
Therefore it seems that "when" in ancient Japanese was the same as today's word "いつ".
And ばかり is a word of emphasis.
Add a predicate of an interrogative sentence to this phrase, and it is like this.

```
いつなりや
```

Comment: The OP might be interested to know that `いつ` today is not pronounced the same way as Old Japanese `いつ` was.  Today `つ` is *tsu*, but it was originally *tu*; that *s* didn't appear until Late Middle Japanese (*A History of the Japanese Language*, Frellesvig p.322).

Comment: And according to the same book, word-internal consonants were likely to gain voicing, in this case it might have been _idu_ (phonetically).